# Redis AOF rewrite issue, no new client connections

Tags: redis

My Redis instance has apparently stopped rewriting AOF file (it has grown to many Gbs). What is worse, it seems to stop serving new client connections (when connecting with redis-cli, connection goes through, but then it freezes on any command). That means that I cannot ask for BGREWRITEAOF. At the same time, existing connections are being served normally.

Log file doesn't show anything useful. redis-check-aof just reports that AOF file is not corrupted. I really don't want to restart the server as I don't know how long it's going to start with such a huge AOF file.

Is there a way to call AOF rewrite externally? Anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've just hit this Redis bug: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2883 :(